# Accessing custom photo album

Tags: ios, uiimage, image-gallery, alassetslibrary

My app creates unique photographs for the users then saves them in a custom photo album with this:

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library saveImage:thisimage toAlbum:@"Test Album" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"Album save error: %@", [error description]);
    }
}];
```

When the user enters the application I want to give them a custom slider which shows the photos they saved in the "Test Album" previously. How do I get the photos only in the "Test Album" as UIImages so I can show them to the user??

Answer (score 0):

1) Enumerate the groups in the ALAsset library using `enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:`.

2) Check if the group's `ALAssetsGroupPropertyName` is equal to the album name that you are searching for using `valueForProperty:`.

**Ex.**

```
NSString * groupName = [group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName];
[groupName localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:albumName] == NSOrderedSame
```

3) Once you have found the group, enumerate the assets within it using `enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:`.

4) For every `ALAsset` retrieve it's `defaultRepresentation` and from that it's `fullScreenImage`.

**Ex.**

```
ALAssetRepresentation * assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
CGImageRef imageRef = [assetRepresentation fullScreenImage];
```

5) For every `ALAsset` retrieve it's `UIImageOrientation` using `ALAssetPropertyOrientation` and `valueForProperty:`.

**Ex.**

```
 UIImageOrientation imageOrientation = [[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyOrientation] intValue];
```

6) For every `ALAsset` alloc/init a `UIImage` using `imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:`. Then, plug in the `fullScreenImage` and `UIImageOrientation` that you retrieved in the steps 4 and 5.

**Ex.**

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:1.0f orientation:imageOrientation];
```

7) Once you have alloc'd/init'd the `UIImage` add it in to a `NSMutableArray`.

8) Once the enumeration is complete, present the images to the user.

**Note:**

Both of the methods used to enumerate Groups and Assets are asynchronous meaning that they will return immediately.

Comment: example for the 1st one will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple..I add my code.

```
    [_library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll  usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop){

    if ([[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqual:@"Test Album"]) {
        void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
        {
            if(result != nil)
            {
                [self.assets addObject:result]; //assets is NSMutableArray
            }
        };

            [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
            [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:assetEnumerator];
    }

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
                      failureBlock:^(NSError *error){

                          NSLog(@"failure"); }];}
```

Hope this is helpful ,....Enjoy.